# Unable to generate badrecord file in spark local

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark

I need to write all the bad records from a input csv file to badrecordfile in spark local. I am using eclipse for the same.

Code:

```
    inputDFRdd = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
        .option("badRecordsPath", "/src/test/resources/bad.txt")
        .option("delimiter", ";")
        .option("header", "false")
        .schema(customSchema)
        .option("escape", "\"").load(filepath).rdd.zipWithIndex().map(line => Row.fromSeq(Seq(line._2 + 1) ++ line._1.toSeq)
```

Comment: Mode "DROPMALFORMED" can be removed.

Comment: Thankyou pasha701, but no still not able to, when dropmalformed is removed, default mode "permissive" is taken into account

Answer (score 1):

This badRecords file creation is a specific feature of databricks.This not gonna work in local mode.